# Electrolytic 3-lead capacitor

Tags: capacitor, identification, electrolytic-capacitor

I have a 3-lead capacitor that I'm having a hard time identifying. It is from an old Lafayette PF-30 receiver. I don't have schematics or a manual.

It has a high squeal when turned on, and my first order of business is to replace the electrolytic caps.

[image]

Comment: It's two capacitors in one can.

Comment: Do you have a question, a real problem?

Comment: If you cannot find an equivalent in a single package, replace it with two capacitors with their negative terminals connected together.

Comment: Also, "MFD" is "old" for "microfarad", which today would be uF. Do not confuse with mF which is millifarad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with this particular brand, but this is what I have seen so far for 3 lead capacitors:

1. The third lead not connected to anything. Its only role being an additional mechanical support.
2. The third lead internally connected to the negative terminal, maybe still serving as a mechanical support. Sometimes the PCB designer being lazy enough and the third lead not connected.
3. Two capacitors in one package with common negative (rare)
4. Two capacitors in one package in series (one negative and one positive at the common lead - even more rare)

Your best strategy is probably to trace the PCB around the capacitor. Desoldering the capacitor may reveal additional markings on its bottom.

Comment: This is definitely two capacitors in one--note that it has two separate capacitance ratings (they're identical, but that just means there are two identical capacitors in there).

Comment: #3 is not rare in old equipment: it was very common. It's what this object is.

Comment: @Hearth Maybe. Do you decode the symbols to the left of the "1000MDF" ?

Comment: @fraxinus Probably there are identical markings next to the capacitor terminals, to know which terminal is which. Only necessary to know the negative if they're both the same, but I imagine the same system is used for combinations of two different capacitances.

Comment: The symbols correspond to marks next to the terminals, which aren't shown.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. I'd only ever seen a 3 lead capacitor in HVAC equipment.  I had thought this might be a dual cap but I've never seen one used in an application like this.

Comment: Better targeted link, look at picure: https://www.edaboard.com/threads/negative-terminal-of-capacitor-to-ground.235421/#post-1004898

Comment: Looks like it’s made by Matsushita (Panasonic). The multi-caps fell out of favour as the technology progressed and the components got smaller. You could hack out the interior and repopulate the can with two modern caps. You might also find the capacitor is still ok. There’s a lot of voodoo regarding recapping - some of it just plain false. The number of retro items I’ve seen recapped with cheapo caps worse than the originals.